# Capacitor: How to control the viewport on iOS (Content under notch)

Tags: ios, viewport, statusbar, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I am dropping Capacitor into a fresh Vue-CLI generated PWA. After running the project in Xcode on an iPhone XS I immediately notice the viewport of the app starts under the notch and ends under the home "button".

I don't ever want content to be under the notch or status bar and just want to be able to style it with the Status Bar plugin.

- `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` is set to `YES`
- `viewport-fit=cover` on the viewport meta is not present
- `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` meta is set to `default`
- Not using Ionic

Comment: Did you solved that?

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1276